# Animated TV series about rich British kid and antagonist with a talking rat

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

When I was a kid I remember watching an animated TV show about this posh rich British kid who played the violin and lived in like the 17th or 18th century. He wore like the kerchief tie thing and short with the long socks like from the Hamilton musical. The antagonist was like his uncle or servant who had a talking rat in his pocket. The ending theme was violin music with a song that said the kid's name but I can't remember it.

It wasn't *Liberty's Kids*.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! You may want to take the [tour] to better understand how the site works. Note, or course, that our site is for questions about fantasy and science fiction. What about this show makes it fit that description? The talking rat alone may not really be enough to qualify it, if that's the only fantastical element. Please [edit] additional information into the question itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

It sounds a lot like *[Wunderkind Little Amadeus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wunderkind_Little_Amadeus)* (aka *Little Amadeus*), a cartoon about Mozart when he was a child. One of the characters has a talking rat named Monti and is constantly trying to disgrace Amadeus in favor of his nephew Mario.

### Opening Theme